# Showing PopupMenuItem horizontally

Tags: dojo

I want to show PopupMenuItem horizontally , but can't find a way to do this.

I am adding it like this

```
 var pSubMenu2 = new Menu();
  pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy"
  }));
  pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut"

  }));
  pMenu.addChild(new PopupMenuItem({
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste",
    popup: pSubMenu2
  }));
```

below is the link of code

```
https://jsfiddle.net/agha_ali22/ntkhy9q3/2/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 pSubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy",
        style: "display:inline"
    }));
    pSubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
       iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut",
       style: "display:inline"
    }));
```

Add `display:inline`  to each subMenu child you want to show Horizontally.

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/an90dr/27uo0hpo/

Comment: One more question how can i hide the submenu on unhover?

Comment: You can add the pSubMenu to the scope of the widget like this: this.pSubMenu. Then you can add an event on mouseleave and close the popup. You can see the example below: https://jsfiddle.net/an90dr/27uo0hpo/

Comment: That one hides the submenu even if hover it on its parent menu and does not show up again